# GCM server using app engine for java not working

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

So i have followed the GCM Demo application tutorial. http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

I got it working with jetty server.
But now i would like to do the app engine for java server and it is not working.
I am sure that my client is configured oke, because it was working for jetty server.

In ApiKeyInitializer.java i replaced "replace_this_text_by_your_Simple_API_Access_key" with my access key.

I copied the appengine sdk to a simple location D:\appenginesdk
Than i run in cmd:

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=D:\appenginesdk runserver -Dserver.host=192.168.0.101
```

Where 192.168.0.101 is my local ip.

```
D:\gmcserverapp>ant -Dsdk.dir=D:\appenginesdk runserver -Dserver.host=192.168.0.101
Buildfile: D:\gmcserverapp\build.xml

init:

copyjars:

compile:
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to D:\gmcserverapp\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes
[javac]
[javac]           WARNING
[javac]
[javac] The -source switch defaults to 1.7 in JDK 1.7.
[javac] If you specify -target 1.5 you now must also specify -source 1.5.
[javac] Ant will implicitly add -source 1.5 for you.  Please change your build file.
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with-source 1.5
[javac] 1 warning
datanucleusenhance:
[enhance] DataNucleus Enhancer (version 1.1.4) : Enhancement of classes
[enhance] DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 0 classes. Timings :input=156 ms, enhance=0 ms, total=156 ms. Consult the log for full details
[enhance] DataNucleus Enhancer completed and no classes were enhanced. Consult the log for full details

runserver:
 [java] aug 21, 2012 1:17:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
 [java] INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
 [java] aug 21, 2012 1:17:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
 [java] INFO: Successfully processed D:\gmcserverapp\WebContent\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
 [java] aug 21, 2012 1:17:55 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
 [java] INFO: Successfully processed D:\gmcserverapp\WebContent\WEB-INF/web.xml
 [java] aug 21, 2012 3:17:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
 [java] INFO: The server is running at http://192.168.0.101:8080/
 [java] aug 21, 2012 3:17:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
 [java] INFO: The admin console is running at http://192.168.0.101:8080/_ah/admin
```

This is what i get in the emulator

[image: emulator android 4.1 with google api]

And in the browser i get no device registered.

What can i do?

What am i doing wrong?

I did a lot of tutorials, nothing worked, i am becoming desperate.

EDIT 2012-08-21 15:57:

Thanks Yahor10, that solved some errors.
I now get this error:

```
 [java] aug 21, 2012 1:52:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
 [java] WARNING: No file found for: //register
```

EDIT 2012-08-21 16:18:

```
 //   String serverUrl = SERVER_URL + "/register";
 String serverUrl = SERVER_URL;
```

I changed the server_url in serverUtilities.java for the android app. This made the emulator say that it is connected. But when i refresh 192.168.0.101:8080 it still gives No devices.....

Answer (score 1):

I had been having similar difficulties with the GCM demo until I figured out that the server_url I had was incorrect. I had set it to 'http://< my_ip_address>:8080/gcm-demo' as the example and tutorial suggest. And whats more, ant was giving me a log for everytime the app tried to contact the server, so I didn't think the url was incorrect.

But I just took out the '/gcm-demo' from the end of the url and it works like a charm.

Hope this was/is what was giving you a headache.

-Mrdresden

Comment: Sounds good, but this is not my problem.
It gives no registered devices, but i can go to 
http://< my_ip_address>:8080

Answer (score 0):

Set 1.7 java code in your server build.xml

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile the Java classes.">
    <javac destdir="${classes}" debug="true" srcdir="${src}" target="1.7"
      includeantruntime="false">
      <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
  </target>
```

Set correct dir location of App engine sdk and
write correct ip address of your computer on the client side

Comment: unregisted,then registed again